# Haskell - Cannot infer instance

Tags: haskell

I have written the following predicate (Lines 94-99)

```
diffFreqMatrix :: Fractional a => [[Rating a]] -> [a]
diffFreqMatrix (x:xs) =  diffFreqMatrixH (x:xs) (matrixPairs (length x))
diffFreqMatrixH _ [] = []
diffFreqMatrixH x ((a,b):ys) = [(diffFreqMatrixH2 x a b 0 0)] ++ diffFreqMatrixH x ys
diffFreqMatrixH2 [] _ _ x y = x / y
diffFreqMatrixH2 (x:xs) a b summ num = if (((x!!a) /= NoRating) && ((x!!b) /= NoRating)) then  diffFreqMatrixH2 xs a b (summ + ((x!!a) - (x!!b))) (num + 1) else diffFreqMatrixH2 xs a b summ num
```

supposedly it calculates an average I want but i'm getting this error

```
ERROR file:.\project.hs:98 - Cannot infer instance
*** Instance   : Fractional (Rating a)
*** Expression : diffFreqMatrixH2
```

Helpers im using in case u want to take a look

```
matrixPairs :: Num a => a -> [(a,a)]
matrixPairs 0 = []
matrixPairs c = matrixPairsH 0 0 (c-1)
matrixPairsH a b c = [(a,b)] ++ if ((b == c) && (a == c)) then [] else if (b == c) then (if (a==c) then [] else matrixPairsH (a+1) 0 c ) else matrixPairsH a (b+1) c


differeneRatings :: Fractional a => Rating a -> Rating a -> a
differeneRatings NoRating (R a) = 0
differeneRatings (R a) NoRating = 0
differeneRatings NoRating NoRating = 0
differeneRatings  (R a) (R b) = a - b
```

Comment: What is `matrixPairs`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added them in, hope it makes the question clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `Rating a`s as if they were just numbers here:

```
(x!!a) - (x!!b)
```

You presumably need to use `case` or similar to pattern match on `x!!a` and `x!!b` to extract the number they contain. You can move the check for `NoRating` into that `case` match to simplify your code. For example:

```
case (x!!a, x!!b) of
    (YesRating ra, YesRating rb) -> diffFreqMatrixH2 xs a b (summ + ra - rb) (num + 1)
    _ -> diffFreqMatrixH2 xs a b summ num
```

Once you get this working the way you want, I encourage you to post to the  [code review StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/); your code can be cleaned up significantly to be both simpler and faster.

Comment: oh lol that's so stupid of me, I just used differeneRatings that I posted up there instead of subtracting and it's all good now, thanks for your help <3